# How to list pairs of consecutive rows from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have an array of numpy arrays `df` and I want to list the pairs of consecutive rows? How do I do that?

I only know how to list each row one at a time and combine them into a list like this: `z=[x for x in df]`. Then I'd do `[np.vstack(z[i],z[i+1]) for i in range(len(z))]`.

I'm just wondering if there's a Pythonic way to do this instead.

My df is for example

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 6., 0., 0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 6., 0., 0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 3., 4., 9., 1., 2., 2., 1., 8.],
       [0., 0., 5., 0., 0., 0., 5., 9., 0.]])
```

And I'd like to return pairs of consecutive arrays at a time.

*** UPDATE

Okay so now I'm trying to return a dataframe where the columns are
(first six entries in the row, the 8th entry, the 7th entry, the 9th entry, and the first six entries in the subsequent row).

When I do `pd.DataFrame([[np.array([df1[1,:,:][j][:6],df1[1,:,:][j][7],df1[1,:,:][j][6],df1[1,:,:][j][8],df1[1,:,:][j+1][:6]])] for j in range(len(df1[1,:,:])-1)])` it looks fine and I get

```
                                                    0
0   [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 0.0, 1.0, 1.0...
1   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
2   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
3   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
4   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
```

.

However, when I do

`pd.DataFrame([[np.array([df1[1,:,:][j][:6],df1[1,:,:][j][7],df1[1,:,:][j][6],df1[1,:,:][j][8],df1[1,:,:][j+1][:6]])] for j in range(len(df1[1,:,:])-1)],columns=['s','a','r','absorb','ns'])` (the only difference is that I provide column names now), I get the error

```
AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns.
```

How do I work around this? Thanks.

Comment: What causes the rows to be consecutive, is there an index?  Can you provide an example df with columns?

Comment: So the array is inside a dataframe or it is numpy array prior to being appended to the dataframe?  Also what do you want your end output to look like?  How many columns in the end?

Comment: No dataframe. It's just a numpy array of numpy arrays.

Comment: On your output, I only see one column "0" that is why you are getting an Assertion Error.  Need to create 5 columns in pd.DataFrame.   Can you show on your desired output something with the columns and output below them.  

Thanks

Comment: Yeah I ended up fixing this.

`pd.DataFrame([np.array([df1[i,:,:][j][:6],df1[i,:,:][j][7],df1[i,:,:][j][6],df1[i,:,:][j][8],df1[i,:,:][j+1][:6]]) for j in range(len(df1[i,:,:])-1)],columns=['state','action','reward','absorb','next state'])`